# Input handling iOS settings page

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently working on a settings page for my app. I am using static table views to setup the UI of the view. My problem is my input handling - i cannot find a structured way of changing the input methods from every cell and saving it.
For example, i have a gender input where i use `UIPickerView` and i then have a age- and weight input where i use `UIDatePickers` configured as valuepickers. How do i program these different input methods in a way, that they are structured.
[image: Screenshot of settings page]
My current thoughts are using a hidden `UITextfield` to show the input methods and altering as the user touches different cells - but i don't know it that would be correct.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use UILabels to display input values in UI. If you do, you could replace them with UITextFields to which you assign your pickers as inputViews and then when cell is tapped you call *tappedTextField.becomeFirstResponder()*. After picker is resigned you update tappedTextField's text value.

Comment: So you mean i should use `UITextFields` to show user settings instead of labels?

Comment: Yes, using UITextField instead of UILabel would be more appropriate in this case  as you can use inputView property to set your picker to it and you display input value there, view hierarchy is more lightweight then having both UILabel and hidden UITextField.